# With below code I'm trying to write to a file in Python but I am getting an error

Tags: python-2.7

Here is the error:

[image: Please find error here]

Here is the code.

```
from sys import argv
first,second=argv
file1=open(second)
print file1.read()
file2=open(second)
file2.write("this is a new line being added to this file\n\n Did you recognize??")
print "check after writing to the file"
print file2.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass second parameter while opening second file.

```
file2=open("second.txt", "a+")
file2.write("text")
file2.close
```

**a** parameter means that you can append text to file.

**w** parameter means that you can write new text to file.

**r** parameter means that you are in read only mode.

Answer (score 0):

file 2 should be opened in write mode!

```
file2 = open(second,"w")
```

or as `r+` mode, that is read and write mode!

```
file2 = open(second,"r+")
```

Comment: Thanks It was helpful